# How to get the first name of each list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if the title isn't clear enough, I have five `<li>'s` in each `<li>` I have `<a>` and a `<div>` and in each `<div>` I have a `<ul>`with a class of "config". Then in that I have two `<li>`.

I use jQuery to hide the `<ul>` with the class of config and then use slideToggle to show/hide them. The problem is, It shows all of them. I want to just click one link and the appropriate `<div>` or `<ul>` should appear, not all of them. How can I do this?

So far I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul.config").hide();
  $("li:nth-child(1) a").click(function(){
    $("li ul.config:first").slideToggle(300);
  });
});​
```

But that only shows the very first list. How can I show each one when it's clicked?

Comment: can you add your html to the question

Answer (score 0):

With not sure of what the HTML really is, try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul.config").hide();
  $("li:nth-child(1) a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('ul.config').slideToggle(300);
  });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

put a class/id to your top-most ul (before 5 top li), e.g: id="topmenu"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul.config").hide();
  $("#topmenu li a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('ul.config').slideToggle(300);
  });
});​
```